# awk print fields from every line in file and the following line

Tags: awk, sed, ksh

I have a file with start and end times per message:

```
msgid=1 11:34:12.410 11:34:12.464
msgid=2 11:34:12.465 11:34:12.563
msgid=3 11:34:12.563 11:34:12.577
msgid=4 11:34:12.849 11:34:12.850
msgid=5 11:34:12.950 11:34:12.951
```

I need to process the elapsed time from the end of one message to the beginning of the next.

This is the best I could come up with to get all the info on one line(I can take it from there) but there has to be a more efficient way with awk and/or sed rather than a while loop.  There are 20K lines in the file so this is pretty slow.

```
var=`cat <file>| wc -l`
i=1
while [[ "$i" -le "$var" ]]; do
  awk 'NR=="'$i'" {print $1, $3}' <file>
  awk 'NR=="'$(($i + 1))'" {print $1, $2}' <file>
  i=$(($i + 1));
done
```

The methods I've tried with awk always advance the record and end up skipping one so I'll get:

```
msgid=1 11:34:12.464 msgid=2 11:34:12.465
msgid=3 11:34:12.577 msgid=4 11:34:12.849
msgid=5 11:34:12.950 <..>
```

Note it's missing comparing msgid 2 and 3 etc.

Any ideas?

Update with output format I would like to see:

```
msgid=1 11:34:12.464 msgid=2 11:34:12.465
msgid=2 11:34:12.563 msgid=3 11:34:12.563
msgid=3 11:34:12.577 msgid=4 11:34:12.849
msgid=4 11:34:12.850 msgid=5 11:34:12.950
```

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: consider editing  your question to include your required output from the sample data you have wisely included in your question. +1 for sample data, code, and good formatting in a your very first question! Keep posting (but with required outputs;-) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you write a shell loop just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. Also, never let shell variables expand within awk scripts as you are currently doing by enclosing your awk script in double quotes. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24.

You show what you DON'T want your output to be but not what you DO want so this is a bit of a guess:

```
$ cat tst.awk
end { print $1, ms($2) - end }
{ end = ms($3) }
function ms(t,   a) {
    split(t,a,/[:.]/)
    return (a[1]*60*60 + a[2]*60 + a[3]) * 1000 + a[4]
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
msgid=2 1
msgid=3 0
msgid=4 272
msgid=5 100
```

You also dont say whether or not the times can wrap around to the next day or if DST is a factor, etc. and if so how to handle that given the lack of a date in your input file.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was going the wrong direction which is why I posted here.  I just couldn't figure out the proper way as I'm fairly new to awk.  There is never a wrap around on the day so I'm not concerned with that.  I can work with this.  Thanks for the help!